# Using OAuth to create accounts in Office 365 with Python

Tags: python, authentication, oauth

I am trying to first get connection to office 365 using python where I'll be able to hit the office 365 api with post request to create accounts. I have seen some solution using Flask and Django. However, I would like to just implement without these framework with a pure python script using only libraries built for doing such. This is a link to the solution in Flask: https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5989

where the api connection is done:

```
    # Put your consumer key and consumer secret into a config file
# and don't check it into github!!
microsoft = oauth.remote_app(
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key=client_id,
    consumer_secret=client_secret,
    request_token_params={'scope': 'User.Read Mail.Send'},
    base_url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
)
```

Also, unlike the Flask solution, I won't be using any views but it will run mainly as a backend task.

I want to replicate the api connection as above using only Python OAuth libraries so it runs as a Python script. So far, I'm only getting a 403 error when I tried curl or using request_oauth. Once I have connection to the api, I'll be able to perform CRUD operations on accounts.

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.